# ACPI.sys causing high Interrupts Usage at 20%

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers

I have been having this odd issue for a while on this ASUS old laptop from 8 years ago (Windows 7 x64). I have noticed that the fan is spinning at max settings so I looked into Process Explorer and noticed that interrupts are at 20% always. I have restarted the laptop and the problem persisted. The laptop has two graphics cards Intel and nVidia. Disabling nVidia caused the interrupts to go to ~1%. I have recovered the laptop to factory settings and the issue was gone.

I have updated Windows and applied all updates. Then, the problem returned. Though, this time it is different. The interrupts are at 20% the same, though, the problem is not there all the time. The problem happens after long usage. If I work on the laptop for 3-5 hours it works without issues, then the problem arises and persists. Though, restarting the laptop actually fixes the issue (interrupts go back to ~1%) and the laptop works for hours before this happening again. To reiterate, the problem persists until I perform a restart.

I have used both Latency Monitor and Window Performance Tools and traced the issue to ACPI.sys on the Microsoft tool and ACPI.sys / ndis.sys on Latency Monitor (ndis.sys happened only on first test, further tests the issue was not there). Here are the results:

**LatencyMon:**
https://i.ibb.co/cb77jjk/1.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/CJ3pKmN/2.jpg

**Windows Performance Analyzer:**

DPC
https://i.ibb.co/g4v69m8/3.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/9bmgHYR/4.jpg
ISR
https://i.ibb.co/NCZG2tH/5.jpg

I have tried several of the suggestions in here. Disabled Wake on Magic Packet option on Ethernet (plus the other Wake on option). Disabled Ethernet altogether. Peformed chkdks c: /f. Disable those enhancements on both Speakers and Mic from audio settings. Tried installing the latest Intel Rapid Storage technology but it would not let me. Says incompatible even though I picked the right OS. I guess the new version requires specific chipsets. Went to Asus websites and made sure I have all drives updated. Tried Advanced Power Settings then turning off PCIE settings.

Thanks for taking the time to read my issue, hopefully someone will be able to assist me as I am at the end of my rope.

Comment: Went to Asus websites and made sure I have all drivers updated.  <-- Make sure BIOS and Chipset were also updated. The laptop may need cleaning inside - the fan may be full of dust. I suggest attending to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the information. I came across the thread with dirt inside the fan. Though, I cannot clean it because I lack the expertise and I cannot go to a shop because of the coronavirus. As for BIOS. I am afraid that flashing a new BIOS would result in me having a dead weight for a laptop. I appreciate the information, though. I forgot to say that I have lowered my laptop processing power to 80% and the fan is quiet now but interrupts are at 17%,